# Removing rows in a data frame based on multiple criteria in R with loop function

Tags: r

I hope that I have formatted my question correctly as this is my first time posting and fairly new to R. Below is a small sample of some athlete movement data that I am currently using. My dataset has about 18000 row items and hence wanted to format it with quick R code.

[The sample data is attached herewith for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMy7e.png)

I would like to remove rows of the data frame based on multiple criteria like when selecting price for particular company, with particular product and MRP between a certain range only those rows should be there in the dataframe and all other rows not matching above conditions should be deleted.

I am trying to use the following code in R for getting the desired output but somehow it is showing error while executing.

```
filter(feb_raw,(feb_raw$Company.=="STL" & feb_raw$Product.=="N24" & feb_raw$MRP<=1360 & feb_raw$MRP>=1150))
```

Wondering how I can do this if it's possible with a loop function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `filter` from the `dplyr` package. To be sure, use `dplyr::filter()` instead of just `filter()`. Something I notice is that you have a period after some of your variable names. These don't appear in the screenshot of your data, so maybe that is the problem. Also, when using `filter`, you don't need `feb_raw$` with each variable.

So, potentially corrected code might look like the following:

```
dplyr::filter(feb_raw, Company=="STL" & Product=="N24" & MRP<=1360 & MRP>=1150)
```